# How can I set the type of an object depending of an input value?

Tags: c++, enums, runtime, compile-time, type-deduction

I am writing a function that takes the enum `MyEnum` as input. Depending on the value of MyEnum, I initialize an object and process it. I cannot change the class hierarchy of those objects (their classes), since they are from an external dependency. Processing the newly created object is always the same.

**Question:**

How can I write this "elegantly". I do not want to write a long if, else if, else block that repeats itself over and over, which is what I currently do. What I would like to have is some magic function that tells me the type to use at runtime. Afaik this does not exist.

**What I would like to have:**

```
magic_function(enum_known_at_runtime) my_object;
```

**What I would use if I knew the value at compile time:** [play with code](https://godbolt.org/z/3xcKG1)

```
enum class MyEnum { A, B , /* many more values */ };

template <MyEnum>
struct get_type;

template <>
struct get_type<MyEnum::A> {
  using Type = unsigned int; // some type
};

...

int main() {
    get_type<enum_known_at_compiletime>::Type i;
    // do stuff with i  
}
```

**What I currently do:**

```
if (enum_known_at_runtime == MyEnum::A) {
    // init an object of some type and do stuff with it
} else if (enum_known_at_runtime == MyEnum::A) {
    // init an object of other type and do same stuff with it
} ...
```

Comment: Are all the "init an object" parts the same, except for the type? Same question for the "do stuff with it".

Comment: `std::variant`?

Comment: please include more details, it is difficult to avoid code repetition when it is unknown what code is repeated

Comment: @Bojie Yea, all the same

Comment: @dfri Feels like I have to do an if-else-block later on to `std::get<>` the value from the `std::variant` later on. Am I wrong here?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Think about it as initializing a client. So init a client object of some type using the default constructor, make a few calls via that client, close connection...

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume you capture the repeated code in a templated function and define corresponding instantiations for `get_type`:

```
template <MyEnum E>
struct get_type;

template <MyEnum E>
void init_object_do_stuff() {
    using T = get_type<E>::type;
    T client;
    client.do_stuff();
}
```

You can now write your repeated code as follows:

```
switch (enum_known_at_runtime) {
    case MyEnum::A: init_object_do_stuff<MyEnum::A>(); break;
    case MyEnum::B: init_object_do_stuff<MyEnum::B>(); break;
}
```

Now the work for new enums is adding a single line and an extra case for `get_type`, which you can further shrink using a macro. As a bonus, the compiler will yell at you if your `switch` does not cover all cases.

Comment: Thank you for that idea. Looks quite pretty to me :)